# having a problem getting the result from a sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert2

```js
function confirmation() {
    swal.fire({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Your about to delete some files",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        showConfirmButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, I am sure!',
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    }).then((result) => {

        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            swal.fire("Deleted!", "files are successfully deleted!", "success");
        } else {
            window.location = "....";
        }
    });
}
```

but even if I confirm or deny it just cancels what can I do?
I also tried to use `isDenied` and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For Cancel button in SweetAlert you should use `.isDismissed()` method of SweeetAlertResult Object. Also you used deprecated properties (closeOnConfirm, CloseOnCancel, type):

```
function confirmation() {
    swal.fire({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Your about to delete some files",
        icon: 'success',
        showCancelButton: true,
        showConfirmButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, I am sure!',
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel it!",
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            swal.fire("Deleted!", "files are successfully deleted!", "success");
            console.log("Delete files...")
        }
        if (result.isDismissed) {
            swal.fire("Cancelled!", "Files not deleted!", "warning");
            console.log("Doing Nothing")
        }
    });
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sdurwc9y/

Click Cancel button is equal to click outside modal SweetAlert window. So you can just use `else` instead of `if (result.isDismissed)`.

Comment: i still don't have anything even in the console

Comment: Try out last version of SweetAlert. CDN link in JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sdurwc9y/